# RSpec: setting request headers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm trying to set important headers with `ActionDispatch` `request` helper method in my specs:

```
RSpec.describe API::V1::FoosController, type: :request do
  describe 'GET #index' do
    context 'common case' do
      request.env.merge!({'HTTP_FOO': 'FOO'})
      get api_foos_path, {}, {Accept: Mime::JSON}
    end
  end
end
```

But this header (and generally any header set with `request`) disappears when it comes to controller:

```
class API::V1::FoosController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json, :xml

  def index
    request.env.has_key? 'HTTP_FOO' # false
    respond_with serialize_models(Foo.all)
  end
  # ...
end
```

Why does it happen and how do I set it properly?
Setting the header with `request.header` or `@request.header` does the same.

P.S.: I know I can set headers as a third parameter of `Rack::Test::Methods` helpers, but I don't want to violate DRY - I'd like Mime formats only to be defined there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try like this:

```
request.env['HTTP_FOO_HEADER'] = 'foo header'
```

Comment: Adding environmental keys/values in a different way, unfortunately, changes nothing.

Comment: I tested this code snippet with `rspec 3.3.0` and `rails 4.2.5.1`. It works.

Comment: Did you test it with controller specs?

Comment: Yes, I tested it with controllers.

Comment: It doesn't work with request ones, see comments for an answer abowe.

Comment: This works, thank you so much. This is the first reply I've found that actually takes into account that I'm trying to do this in a controller spec.

Answer (score 0):

Use `controller.request.headers`:

```
controller.request.headers['HTTP_FOO'] = 'FOO'
```

I can verify that this approach works in Rails 4.2.5, as this is lifted directly from real-world code.

Our tests look like this:

```
describe SomeController, type: :controller do
  let(:current_user) { create :user }

  before :each do
    controller.request.headers['Authorization'] = "APIKey #{current_usser.api_key}"
  end
end
```

And our `ApplicationController` looks (more or less) like this:

```
before_action :authenticate_request

def authenticate_request
  key = request.headers['Authorization']
  user = User.find_by(api_key: key)
  # raise AuthenticationError unless user, etc etc
end
```

Comment: I also use Rails 4.2.5, but... it doesn't wok. Which version of rack, rspec-core do you use?

Comment: @DreamWalker `gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0'`, Rack 1.6.4

Comment: mine are `rspec-core-3.0.4`, `rspec-rails-3.0.2` and same version of `rack`, can you provide a piece of code where this approach works?

Comment: @DreamWalker See updated. It could be the lacking `type: :controller` in your spec.

Comment: you are right - the difference is in spec type, it does work with `controller` specs, but doesn't with `request` ones. Controller specs, in turn, have dozen of other caveats :( Neverthless, thank you.